# Como acessar um ponteiro dentro de uma estrutura?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Preciso saber como acessar a primeira posição do vetor de ponteiros *c_parte_real, conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
typedef struct{

   struct char_vector{
      char *c_parte_real[2], *c_parte_imag[2];
   }c_vector;

   struct int_vector{
      int *i_parte_real[2], *i_parte_imag[2];
   }i_vector;

   struct complex_num{
      float real1,real2,imag1,imag2;
   }comp_num;

}expressao_complexa;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dei uma simplificada pra ficar mais claro, criei uma variável pra receber a valor da posição

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {


typedef struct char_vector{
char *c_parte_real[2], *c_parte_imag[2];
}c_vector;



char  a,b;//variável que recebe o valor
c_vector x;

x.c_parte_real[0]='2';
a = x.c_parte_real[0];

x.c_parte_real[1]='3';
b = x.c_parte_real[1];

printf("a=%c\n",a);//imprime na tela
printf("b=%c\n",b);//imprime na tela

return 0;
}
```

teste no :https://repl.it/languages/c

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que você declare uma variável `x`, do tipo `expressao_complexa`, o acesso pode ser feito diretamente:

```
...
expressao_complexa x;

// atribui um valor
x.c_vector.c_parte_real[0] = "1.0"; 

// imprime o valor atribuído
printf("%s\n", x.c_vector.c_parte_real[0]); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As respostas acima estão corretas, mas, seu códido está errado, você não pode declarar estruturas dentro de declaração de estruturas. O que você pode fazer é ter estruturas como componentes de declarações de estruturas.